# Does Substrate's underlying gossip network use MACs to authenticate message validity?

Tags: gossip

## Overview

In the gossip network used by Substrate (based on Libp2p) messages are sent between peers. A few questions come to mind when building on top of this gossip network (sending new messages and building additional gossip protocols).

1. Are MACs appended to messages before they hit the wire or before or never?
2. Do protocol developers have to add MACs to prevent peers from tampering with sensitive messages?

### Example

We execute and coordinate an MPC over protocols built on top of Substrate's gossip primitives. We gossip encrypted payloads to the peers and attempt decrypt each message to identify if its for oneself. If any bits are added to these messages, decryption would undenaibly fail, and so we're curious if we need to handle this ourselves as well.. that messages aren't tampered with in transit.